# Is it possible to make a matrix with rows that have different #rows on Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to make a matrix, or another kind of variable that as rows. The thing is that with the first row there can be 10 numbers(columns), and the second only 3, and the third 5, and so on...
Is that possible? And how?

EDIT: I need to through a matrix, then store the numbers. It's a m-by-2 matrix. I'm going through it with a for loop. Like so:

```
rows = size (mtx, 1);
for i = 1 : rows
    var = m (i, :);
    if m(2) is in A{something}
        if m(3) is in A{something}
            continue (ignore)
        else
            store m(3) in A{something}
        end
    else
        if m(3) is in A{something}
            store m(2) in A{something}
        else store both m(2) and m(3) in A{Newsomething}
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as a matrix, but as a [cell array](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), yes:

```
A{1} = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
A{2} = [1 2 3];
A{3} = [1 2 3 4 5];

>> A
A =
{
  [1,1] =

      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

  [1,2] =

     1   2   3

  [1,3] =

     1   2   3   4   5

}
```

Comment: @peronsintra - am304 is right. You can only achieve staggered matrices using cell arrays.  If you want to create matrices, MATLAB requires that all matrices are even. BTW +1.

Comment: Thank you! And at the time of the code I do not know how many "A's"  there will be. Is it still possible?

Comment: Yes, probably with a `for` loop. You need to provide more information on your exact problem if you want a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the absolute maximum of elements you may have, you might  fill some number of elements with your numbers and all others elements in a row with NaN. After that you could take all non-nan elements from a,say first row, as `A(1, ~isnan(A(1,:)))`

if you need to process all rows, you could write:

```
for i = 1 : size(A,1)
    row_to_process = A(i, ~isnan(A(i,:)))
    do_some_stuff(row_to_process)
end
```