# Is it possible to have a matrix with different row sizes in C++ ?

Tags: c++, matrix

I need to read from a file some ints.
The first int indicates how many ints I will have in that line.

Example:

```
5 1 4 7 10 2
4 5 6 7 1
3 1 0 8
3 4 5 6
4 1 2 3 4
```

Is there a way to create a matrix like this?

I saw that there's a way of doing something similar but it isn't with matrix:
[Is it possible to make a matrix with rows that have different #rows on Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233020/is-it-possible-to-make-a-matrix-with-rows-that-have-different-rows-on-matlab)

Comment: a vector of vectors?

Comment: Yes, use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with your question? If you simply need to store the ints in memory without particular processing needs, a simple std::vector<std::vector<int>> would work.

Comment: That's not a matrix. A matrix is rectangular.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: It's. not a matrix. which is by definition rectangular. But you can create "ragged arrays" with a vector of vectors, or by allocating a list of pointers then allocating each row independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a *jagged edged* matrix.

In mathematical modelling this is normally a most undesirable thing indeed, but in your *particular* case, a

`std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

will model this perfectly. Be mindful that the properties of an `int` vary from platform to platform. The minimum range an `int` can take is -32767 to + 32767. Consider using a `long` &c. if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have 2-d arrays with different row sizes in C++ (If this is what you mean by matrix).
You can use some C++ std library container or some workaround to overcome this limitation. Some options are:

- Array of pointers where each pointer points to an array (usually dynamically allocated) of required size.
- Array of `std::vector` or other container. Or `std::vector`, `std::array` or other container of `std::vector`. (For ex: `std::vector< std::vector< T > >`)
- 2-d array with max row size.

In all of the above approaches data of rows is **not** contiguous. To make data contiguous (if required), you may create a class of your own which creates a big 1-d array and emulate it as a 2-d array.

Comment: "No, it is not possible to have 2-d arrays with different row sizes. " - Starting your answer with "No", when  there are three other answers explaining how to achieve what the OP wants, seems ... odd.  I can see what the question you are trying to answer is, but I see no evidence that it is the question the OP asked.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes natively it is not supported. So I proposed workarounds. Other answers start with WA.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree.  `std::vector` is every bit as much a part of C++ as arrays are.

Comment: @MartinBonner vector is very much part of C++, but it is not an array of arrays or a 2D array or a matrix.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks. Rephrased as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Matrices are by definition rectangular. So, what you are describing is not a matrix. It is a jagged array.

You cannot have an array of arrays where the subarrays are different sized. All elements of an array must have the same type. But you can have an array of pointers, which can point to arrays of any size. A simplest solution is to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec_of_vecs;
```

This is actually the simplest way to represent a 2 dimensional array structure (jagged or not), although the memory representation isn't contiguous like you would expect from a non jagged 2D array.

---

For performance, it is possible to store the arrays in a single memory block as well, but that is going to be much more complicated. What you can do, is to allocate a single block of memory that contains all of the rows, and another array to store pointers to beginnings of each row.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`   i.e. a `std::vector` with elements of type `std::vector<int>`.

The individual `std::vector<int>`s can be of different sizes.